# How to store 00 in an array?

Tags: c, printf, srand

I store four numbers in my array, `00,11,22,33`. When I generate a random number and print it, it displays `0` rather than `00` (when the first element is selected). The other numbers are fine and displaying correctly. How can I store 00 in an array so that it displays properly?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>  

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int myArray[4] = { 00,11,22,33 };
    int randomIndex = rand() % 4;
    int randomIndex1 = rand() % 4;
    int randomIndex2 = rand() % 4;
    int randomIndex3 = rand() % 4;

    int randomValue = myArray[randomIndex];
    int randomValue1 = myArray[randomIndex1];
    int randomValue2 = myArray[randomIndex2];
    int randomValue3 = myArray[randomIndex3];
    printf("= %d\n", randomValue);
    printf("= %d\n", randomValue1);
    printf("= %d\n", randomValue2);
    printf("= %d\n", randomValue3); 

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Umm, 00 equals 0. So the program is displaying correctly.

Comment: Don't get fancy with formatting and indentation. Indent only nested. And read about the difference between integers and strings/character sequences.

Answer (score 2):

`00` the number, is exactly the same as `0` the number, while `11` is obviously a different number from `1`.

Consider storing strings instead. Alternatively, if you want to display `00`, just 2 characters using `%02d` as your formatting string:

```
printf("= %02d\n", randomValue);
```

If this really is your whole program, you could even just modify your array and then print values  twice ex:

```
int myArray[4] = {0,1,2,3};
. . .
printf("= %d%d\n", randomValue, randomValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `%02d` scan code will prints the random number with zero padding:

```
printf("%02d\n", randomValue);
// Expected output for 0: 00
                          ^
                     This 0 belongs to the scan code
```

Also, the `%2d` scan code will do blank space padding for you:

```
printf("%2d\n", randomValue);
// Expected output for 0:  0
                          ^
                     This space belongs to the scan code
```

In general `%(0)NM` is a scan code where:

- `0` is optional and it belongs to numbers and if it is used, it will add zero padding to the output; if it is not used, it will add blank space padding.
- `N` is the number of digits/characters you want to print e.g. `2`.
- `M` is the scan code you want to have to show your data type e.g. `{d, x, c, s, ...}` standing for `{number, hexadecimal number, character, string, ...}`

You can find a complete list of scan codes [here](http://www.cdf.toronto.edu/~ajr/209/notes/printf.html).